# how to remove class name from references in mongodb+datanucleus

Tags: java, mongodb, jdo, datanucleus

I have two classes with 1-1 relations. classes are final, so there is no inheritance.

```
@PersistantCapable
@DatastoreIdentity(strategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
class A {  
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(name = "_id")
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT
    long id; 
}

class B { A a; }
```

The whole system works correctly, but references represented in very inefficient way. For instance: { a: "full.class.name.A:3" }. I want to remove class names and use integers to store IDs, this will improve speed (especially on indexes) and disk space consumption.

Comment: You cannot use DatastoreIdentity and also have a PrimaryKey field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple looking at [their code](https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/mongodb/fieldmanager/StoreFieldManager.java#L600) suggests you would have to contribute something like that as an option, raise an issue and contribute the update to the code. It wouldn't likely be the default option since in 90+% of systems there is inheritance so the class of the related object is usually important. MongoDB also seems to support "DBRef", not sure how efficient that is, but it is marked in that code as a TODO.